# Haven't been able to get google maps on android with out crashing at all

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Over the past couple of days, I have been trying many tutorials on getting google maps api on android. I have had no luck at all, everytime I launch the app it crashes. Here is my code, all I want to do is display a map - that's it!

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.gettinggmapsworking;


import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.example.R;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;




@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
 {


  static final LatLng MUMBAI = new LatLng(19.0144100, 72.8479400);
  private GoogleMap map;

  @Override

  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
      {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(MUMBAI, 15));

    // Zoom in, animating the camera.
    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);
  }
}
```

Here is my activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

 <fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And finally here is my manifest:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<permission android:name="com.example.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.mapexplore.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

     <!-- Your API key needs to be added over here -->
     <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyB_kvQ38jYvL9BlEgRw6P-7bw-No_Ose9s" />

</application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your activity name in your manifest is wrong.  It should be `com.example.gettinggmapsworking.MainActivity`.  Your activity tag inside your manifest would become:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.gettinggmapsworking.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Do i replace the layout with this?

Comment: No.  Inside your manifest, you need to change the android:name attribute in your activity tag.  You left "gettinggmapsworking" out of the package name. I'll add the full activity tag to my answer.